# redux-persist not working in server side rendering in react universal app

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering, redux-persist

Recently I implemented server side rendering in my existing react app and persist is not not working in server side and store is empty in server side on page refresh. Persist is working fine with client side.

I'm mentioning my code.Just have a look on it:

```
const encryptor = createEncryptor({
  secretKey: key
});
const persisted_state = undefined; //loadState()
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
  transforms: [encryptor],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2 // see "Merge Process" section for details.
};
const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
// console.log("REDUCERS",reducer)
const app = createReactAppExpress({
  clientBuildPath,
  universalRender: handleUniversalRender,
  onFinish(req, res, html) {
    const { helmet } = helmetCtx;
    const helmetTitle = helmet.title.toString();
    const helmetMeta = helmet.meta.toString();
    const newHtml = html
      .replace('{{HELMET_TITLE}}', helmetTitle)
      .replace('{{HELMET_META}}', helmetMeta);
    res.send(newHtml);
  },
  onEndReplace(html) {
    const state = store.getState();

    return html.replace(
      '{{SCRIPT}}',
      `${tag}<script>
      window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(state).replace(
        /</g,
        '\\u003c'
      )};
      window.__INITIAL_DATA__ = ${JSON.stringify(serverData).replace(
        /</g,
        '\\u003c'
      )};
    </script>`
    );
  }
});

function handleUniversalRender(req, res) {
  const context = {};
  helmetCtx = {};
  const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
  store = createStore(pReducer,persisted_state, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return getInitialData(req, res,routes)
  .then(data => {
      serverData = data;
      const app = (
        <HelmetProvider context={helmetCtx}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
              <AppClass routes={routes} initialData={data} store={store}/>
              </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
          </StaticRouter>
        </HelmetProvider>
      );
      return app;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.send(500);
    });
}
```

Any help or solution to implement persist in server side will be greatly appreciated.